# how to check current value of UploadReadAheadSize

Tags: 2007, iis

Is there any way I can find out what's the current value or file size limit of UploadReadAheadSize for IIS on windows server 2003.

Comment: Please note that the second option on this page does not work in II6 (Windows 2003). Apparently there is no appcmd file in IIS6. This file is a feature of IIS7 (Windows 2008) and newer Windows server OSs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adsutil get w3svc/UploadReadAheadSize
```

Above command worked for me and thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you cant access it as there is no interface to get the value, the default value is 48kb I belive.

if its related to you uploading a file, the default size limmit is set to 50mb by default.

These settings (default settings) have been inplace for DOS attack i think hence why they are small in size! There are a couple of ways you can change it if a third party needs to use it that you need it to....

for this you need to change the metabase to a higher values like so:

you need to use Adsutil with the following script:

```
Adsutil set w3svc/uploadreadaheadsize "100000000"
```

it sets it to 100mb

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/48900606-4881-4a93-a4c1-0e0ac622fee6.mspx?mfr=true

or

open cmd

add this command `cd..` untill you get to the root `c://`

add this `cd c:\Windows\systems32\inetsrv`

then add the following command:

```
appcmd set config "My Site/MyApp" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:104857600 -commitpath:apphost
```

or add the following to app.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="65535" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Or you can use this third party app to see the values ;)

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa108.htm

hope it helps :)

Comment: iv ammended the answer to contain a thirdparty app to lookup the values for you